# Generic Any/Attach/Add function for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, iphone, generics

Looking through my EF classes, they're littered with code that looks like this:

```
if (_myContext.[EntityType].Any(d => d.RowId == dc.RowId))  
{
    _myContext.[EntityType].Attach(dc);
    _myContext.Entry(dc).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
else
{
    _myContext.[EntityType].Add(dc);
}
```

It's the same thing over and over, and is clearly itching to be handled by a generic function.

However, I'm not sure how you'd go about handling the need for it to deal with a variety of unexpected entity types. A good example to get me started would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Here is some of my older code (I now use a base class rather than dynamics), but this should get you going.  It's only for an update, but should hopefully show the general idea.

```
public void GenericSetItemIsActive<T>(int id) where T : class
{
    using (var db = new HotSpottingContext())
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereFunction = m => m.As<dynamic>().ID == id;

        var selectedItem = db.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(whereFunction);

        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            dynamic dynamicItem = selectedItem;
            dynamicItem.IsActive = !dynamicItem.IsActive;

            db.Entry(dynamicItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, bear in mind that using an `Expression` allows the DB to do the work, if you use `Func` thhen all rows will be retrieved, so, well, don't do that... :)